# Xcode doesn't recognize Enums

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8, xcode9, swift3.2

I made a project with Xcode 9 beta and now for release it I have to use Xcode 8 for archiving and releasing,but when try to build with Xcode 8,some error accord.
I have an enum that works correctly in Xcode 9,but Xcode 8 can not recognize members of that.

```
enum TestAcceptionStatus:Int {
case pricePending = 1
case payReady
case payed
case testerPending
case admissionRegistration
case testerDetail
case sampleRegistration
case answered = 20 }
```

this is the error image:

[image: this is the error image]

so, can anybody help me !!

Comment: Try to create a variable containing the value then apply the switch statement to that

Comment: try with if else if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.
Just should unwrap statusType from switch condition.
this may be an Xcode bug,because statusType is not an optional but when I added `!` at the end of statusType,errors disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    let i : Int = 4
    switch i {
    case TestAcceptionStatus.pricePending.rawValue:
        print("1")
    case TestAcceptionStatus.payReady.rawValue:
        print("2")
    case TestAcceptionStatus.payed.rawValue:
        print("3")
     .
     .
     .
    default:
        print("0")
    }
```